# Visual Basic Download Not Doing Anything On Completion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, download

My other issue was with a bigger file made dynamically but now I'm just doing a small, already existing text file to try and get this concept working at least.

I'm attempting to download a file when the user clicks on the button but after the Response lines run nothing seems to download nor does the browser recognize a possible download.  I've stepped through it as well as it just goes through every line but the front end no download file begins or prompted for.  The file is currently in the bin file of the project and I've also tried just in my own local downloads file.  Just contains "hello" nothing major.

The asp:

```
<asp:button id = "Button1" Class="button"  text = "TEST" runat = "server" />
```

And the vb

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileToDownload = Server.MapPath("~/bin/test.txt")
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt")
    Response.TransmitFile(fileToDownload)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

I've tried the response lines in different orders, as well as just using flush or just end.  This is just a tempt file of course as the bigger scheme is to dynamically create and excel file and download that to the user.

Comment: Does the browser receive any response at all?  Or does it just spin and time out?

Answer (score 0):

edit: sry, i just tried your code as-is and it worked on my machine. i'm using firefox. i've seen some long articles about dealing with internet explorer. any chance you're using that?

---

original post:

can a file be downloaded from bin? just a thought. 
also, try removing `Response.Flush()` and see if that helps. i think Response.End takes care of that - when everything is actually done.

Comment: Nope, using Chrome.  What's weird is that other pages (that create the file differently) are able to download their files (say a copy of a grid display to an excel file).  The method of downloading it is the same though, using Response and such.  

For some reason though this page just won't respond to the code.